# Getting questionmark characters (?) when reading file line by line into worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am reading a text file line by line with VBA into a worksheet. it's often returning these characters. Does anyone know how to remove them?

this is how i am reading it:

```
Sub ReadAsciiFile()

    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer
    Dim sBuf As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    ' edit this:
    sFileName = "usmap.txt"

    ' does the file exist?  simpleminded test:
    If Len(Dir$(sFileName)) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    iFileNum = FreeFile()
    Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

    Do While Not EOF(iFileNum)
        Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
        ' now you have the next line of the file in sBuf
        ' do something useful:
        activesheet.Cells(i, 1) = sBuf
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print sBuf
    Loop

    ' close the file
    Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

Comment: They look like they're representations of unprintable (in the current character set) characters.  What is in the original text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you're copying and pasting into Excel, check your paste method and try "Paste Special" as Text (as opposed to HTML or Unicode Text).

You can also use a simple VBA function to find out what the invalid characters are.  Then you could either use another VBA function to remove the invalid characters or use the Excel formula `Substitute()` function which I showed in the last question you asked.  Here's a quick example of some VBA code to see what characters exist in cell `A1`:

```
Sub PrintChars()
  Dim intLen As Integer
  Dim str As String
  str = Range("A1").Value
  intLen = Len(str)
  Dim intCount As Integer
  intCount = 1

  Dim strChar As String

  Do While intCount <= intLen
    strChar = Mid(str, intCount, 1)
    Debug.Print strChar & ": " & Asc(strChar)
    intCount = intCount + 1
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I would be curious to see what parameters you pass to Substitute function to achieve the replacement, with VBA the "?" is not a real "?", meaning comparison returns false. In my code I can cleanup while skipping real question marks using this statement  'If asc(Mid(.Text, i, 1)) = 63 And Mid(.Text, i, 1) <> "?" Then'